# React updating irregularly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I don't really know why this issue is happening.
It is suppose to update 90 deg every second.
Sometimes it goes crazy and update more 90 degrees sometimes.

[CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/sauravk7077/pen/MWyzyMN?editors=0010)

```
        const updateValue = _=>{
            console.log(this.state.value + 90);
            this.setState(s=>({
                value: s.value + 90
            }))
        }
        this.timerId = setInterval(updateValue, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

"setInterval" and "setTimeOut" out of sync when tab is not focused
you must change your async doThis same as follows:

```
async doThis () {
        const updateValue = _=>{
            if (!document.hidden){ 
                console.log(this.state.value + 90);
                this.setState(s=>({value: s.value + 90}))
            }
            
        }
        this.timerId = setInterval(updateValue, 1000)
    }
```

I did this and I think your problem solved ... plase use this code:

```
const {useState} = React;

class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            value: 0
        }
        this.doThis = this.doThis.bind(this);
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        this.doThis();
    }
    
    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.timerId);
    }
    
    async doThis () {
        const updateValue = _=>{
            if (!document.hidden){ 
                console.log(this.state.value + 90);
                this.setState(s=>({value: s.value + 90}))
            }
            
        }
        this.timerId = setInterval(updateValue, 1000)
    }
    render() {
        return <Box value={this.state.value}/>;
    }
}

function Box(props) {
    const angle = props.value;
    let style = {
        transform: `rotateZ(${angle}deg)`,
        transformOrigin: 'bottom'
    }
    let boxStyle = {
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
    return(
        <div>
            <div className='box' style={boxStyle}>
                <div style={style} className="needle"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Sorry, it seems to slow down the irregularity but not stop it.